# 型アノテーションをつけると__init__で初期化できてなくてもインスタンス化できてしまう

Tags: python, python3

型アノテーションによってエラーが出るタイミングが変わってしまいます。
変数を宣言して初期化をしないクラスを定義します。Test2では型アノテーションだけ実施します。

```
class Test1 :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.a = 1
        self.b

class Test2 :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.a = 1
        self.b : int
```

```
>>> test1 = Test1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
AttributeError: 'Test1' object has no attribute 'b'
```

これは納得できるのですが

```
>>> test2 = Test2()
>>> test2.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Test2' object has no attribute 'b'
```

ここで`test2.b`を参照するまでエラーが出ないのが不思議です。

```
>>> vars(test2)
{'a': 1}
```

`test2.b`が存在しないのはわかるのですが、インスタンス化したときになぜエラーが表示されないのでしょう。

Answer (score 3):

型アノテーションだけの行でエラーが起てしまうようだと「型アノテーションだけをする」というのが不可能になるからです。

---

(追記)
PEP526に記載ありました。
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations

> Being able to omit the initial value allows for easier typing of variables assigned in conditional branches:

```py
sane_world: bool
if 2+2 == 4:
    sane_world = True
else:
    sane_world = False
```

> Omitting the initial value leaves the variable uninitialized:

```py
a: int
print(a)  # raises NameError
```

Comment: 「型アノテーションだけをする」ことが可能と言うことは、初期化せずに変数宣言ができてしまうということでしょうか。とはいえ変数は存在していませんが…
型アノテーションをしているのに変数としては認識されないんですね。

Comment: 名前を束縛するのは代入文ですからね。これは(アノテーションだけをする)式文なので値に名前を束縛しませんよね。

Comment: なるほど、理解できました！
アノテーションは名前を束縛しないものの、エラーは返さないようになってしまっているんですね。
上記内容が発生しないよう対策した上でOptionalで変数を置いておきたいときなどに使ったりする分には良さそうです。
ありがとうございます！